# set up alternative for translateX in older browsers

Tags: html, css

On a website that I have been working on (www.koa-de.nl) I used the following code to center the navigation bar:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

I used this because margin-left: auto + margin-right: auto put the element slightly off-center.

Now I've noticed this doesn't work in older browsers and pushes the menu partly out of screen (due to left: 50%)

How can I work around this? Can I add some code to make sure the navigation is centered on all browsers?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` for centering, or javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't even look like you need the translate and left property.
Try this:

```
.navibar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 65%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 2px;
    border-color: #CF1B19;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The reason why this works is because you already have `position: fixed` on the 
`.navbar-fixed-top` class, along with a `left: 0` and `right: 0`.
 
All you need to do next is set a `margin: 0 auto` to center the nav.

Using this the nav looked perfectly centered to me.